# Use of undefined constant ABSPATH

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WP for the first time. I'm just trying to create a very basic script to echo the user's id and am having all sorts of issues.

The code is this and is currently located in wp-content/plugins (i'm not really sure where these things should be):

```
<?php
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
$user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $user->get_site_id();
```

I'd had it without the require initially but I was getting a `function not defined` error for `wp_get_current_user`. Now I'm getting `Warning: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH'...`

Is there some sort of predefined set of files that I need to include or some specific directory I need to be putting my scripts so that these variables and functions are in scope? My understanding was that these things are supposed to be global.

Comment: Have you created a proper plugin and activated it? https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/

Comment: @jeff, I suppose the plugin should be already normally declared and activated in order to have the error message he describe. Otherwise I think it's impossible to run the code from the plugin. Except if he did manual load of the plugin source code.

Comment: Its just a file in the directory and I'm directly calling its path in the browser

Comment: @cebo as I explain in my comment to my answer below, you are doing it totally wrong. I have attached links to the answer, so you can find how to run your code from inside the WordPress. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try code like that:

```php
add_action('init', 'some_function_name'); 

function some_function_name() { 
    $user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    echo $user->get_site_id();  
}
```

The WordPress comes with hooks (actions and filters) to let other developers modify either core parts of the WordPress or code from other plugins / themes.

The code I describe in my answer, it is running your code when the whole WordPress , all the Plugins and the theme are loaded, thus you should have by default the `wp_get_current_user()` function and you should not need to include manually the `pluggable.php`.

This seems like is going to solve your problem.

Read more on hooks here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/.

Side note. Keep in mind that in order to run your custom code you should register a proper WordPress plugin and activate it. If you have made a php file in the plugins folder, and you loaded using PHP functions like `require/include` the plugin probably will not operate as you expect although the source code it could be perfect. To get more details on how to write your own plugin, you could read here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: I get: 

`Call to undefined function add_action() `

Comment: @cebo then you may do something really bad to the WordPress :) . Read my full answer as I have provide extra information and you will probably find what's wrong with your code. Anyway, if the answer I shared with you, seems like is being the right one, don't hesitate to up vote and click the check-mark under the voting buttons :) Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: Finally let me tell you, that I just tried the exact same code I the one I send you above, and I got the site id, which for my local environment is the number `1`.

Comment: So i think one of the basic questions I have is: Should all custom code be made into a plugin? I feel like for my minimal use case it shouldn't have to be registered as an entire plugin just for me to get the user id.

Comment: It really depends. You didn't really explain in your question what the goal is (other than "I want to get the current user", yeah, but what for?), maybe you don't even need to code a plugin for whatever you're trying to do @cebo (but, again, you need to explain the situation properly so we can provide some guidance.)

Comment: I have a seperate application with its own users. They can have their wp account linked to their user on this application. I want a button on the wp site to link to the other application and also send the user id of the person being sent. Edit: I want the button to call a server side script so that I can hash the user ID too, so not javascript

Comment: For that reason you can also utilise the WordPress Rest API functionality that let's you get information without write a single line of code in the WordPress side. There's no reason to take the value using the code you just described.

Comment: i had to manually include it to use PHPUnit Tests in my plugin